# React-native : The application is slow after running for a long time without being used

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, performance

I’m using React Native to build an application that needs to run 24/7. The application never goes into the background.

This application is constantly communicating via serial-port.

We noticed that if the application runs for 12 hours without being used, when we touch the screen, the application is super slow for a few moments, then returns to normal. But it uses much more RAM than at the beginning.

We first thought it was due to our code, which we had already optimized quite a bit, but we did the test with as little code as possible, as well as without communication with the mainboard and the result is the same.

I’ve looked through the issues, I’ve seen that other people have raised the problem but the posts are 3-4 years old so I don’t know if it’s still current?

Do you know about the problem and/or has it been resolved since the last issues? Are there any workarounds?

I specify that I work in React Native 0.72.3 on devices in Android 8.1. I can give more details if needed but for now I don’t think it’s necessary.

Thank you!

I tested the application with as little code as possible and same result.